# Range of arguments for a Specflow Scenario

Tags: selenium, cucumber, specflow, scenarios

I'm looking to have a Specflow test which processes rows from an external spreadsheet.

As an example this feature produces the exact effect I need. As in a single feature which generates multiple tests which have their test name ammended so I can tell which is which.

```
Scenario Outline: Testing all ten rows
    When I start my test
    Then I can process row <rowNumber>
    And I can see what happens
Examples:
|rowNumber|
|1        |
|2        |
|3        | etc etc
```

However, I'm hoping to perhaps iterate through 100 rows or so. Is there a way I can make the rowNumber argument a range of numbers so I dont have a huge long table in the feature?

I really like how the above feature would actually give me three uniquely named tests so when one fails I can quickly see which row it refers to. I'd prefer this than simply have a massive single test that iterates through all 100 rows and the whole thing fails on just one bad row.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Short answer is no. You could try the excel plugin https://specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-Excel/ (paid thing though) which might help by moving the examples to the spreadsheet I think (though I've not used it). Why we tend to do in this case is put the large table in a single feature file on its own, then its a bit more manageable

Comment: Cheers for your feedback Sam, good to know. I might take a look at the plugin. I did have the data in the feature originally but there are so many columns it was just unmanageable

Comment: if you have a lot of columns how do you think it could work better? Another option (but which won't give you a single test failure) would be to keep the data in a file and have the test iterate the file and execute the code under test for each line in the file, and catch exceptions so it'll always execute all cases and then report which ones failed in the test failure message. 

Not ideal, but sometimes you have to be pragmatic.